# Replicate rows and columns

Tags: r

I have a table contain text of information and I need to replicate each column 3 times

for example

```
A001 A002 
A003 A004
```

I want to make it

```
A001 A001 A001 A002 A002 A002 
A003 A003 A003 A004 A004 A004
```

Is there way to do that for whole table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can repeat `names` of dataframe `n` (here 3) number of times using `rep`

```
rep(names(df), each=3)

#[1] "V1" "V1" "V1" "V2" "V2" "V2"
```

and then

```
df[rep(names(df), each = 3)]

#    V1 V1.1 V1.2   V2 V2.1 V2.2
#1 A001 A001 A001 A002 A002 A002
#2 A003 A003 A003 A004 A004 A004
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A001", "A003"), 
      class = "factor"),V2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A002", "A004"), 
      class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1","V2"), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: When I type rep(names(df), each=3) give me NULL

Comment: @Faisal What is the name of your table? Is that a dataframe or matrix? Try with `rep(colnames(df), each=3)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `replicate`, i.e. -- (Using @Ronak's example)

```
do.call(cbind, replicate(3, list(df)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     V1   V2   V1   V2   V1   V2
> 1 A001 A002 A001 A002 A001 A002
> 2 A003 A004 A003 A004 A003 A004
> ```

To sort the columns to match your expected output (and make the names unique),

```
dd <- do.call(cbind, replicate(3, list(df)))

dd[order(gsub('\\D+', '', names(dd)))]
```

which gives,

> ```
>     V1 V1.1 V1.2   V2 V2.1 V2.2
> 1 A001 A001 A001 A002 A002 A002
> 2 A003 A003 A003 A004 A004 A004
> ```